# calling dll from c# in c

Tags: c#, c, com

i wrote a dll in c# and now i want to use a function from this dll in c.
i can create that object in c.
but i can not call a function for example: hallo().

is there maybee an other way to import dll/com in c?

main.c

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <objbase.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "IExample.h"


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
IExample        *exampleObj;
HRESULT         hr;

if (!CoInitialize(0))
{
    hr = CoCreateInstance(&CLSID_IExample, 0,CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, &IID_IExample, &exampleObj);
    if (hr==S_OK)
    {
         exampleObj->lpVtbl->hallo(exampleObj); //**didnt call the function hallo**
        exampleObj->lpVtbl->Release(exampleObj);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox(0, "Can't create IExample object",
          "CoCreateInstance error",
          MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);

    }

    CoUninitialize();
}
else
{
    MessageBox(0, "Can't initialize COM", "CoInitialize error", MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    return 1;
}


return 0;
    }
```

IExample.h

```
#ifndef _IEXAMPLE_H_
#define _IEXAMPLE_H_

#include <initguid.h>

DEFINE_GUID(CLSID_IExample, 0x0C8C7C5A, 0x729F, 0x43A4, 0x90, 0x06, 0x57, 0x7B, 0xF6, 0x27, 0xFA, 0x75);

DEFINE_GUID(IID_IExample  , 0xD685CD6F, 0x5D76, 0x4868, 0x9C, 0xE4, 0x8A, 0xBB, 0xF6, 0x0A, 0xCA, 0x06);

#undef  INTERFACE
#define INTERFACE   IExample
DECLARE_INTERFACE_ (INTERFACE, IUnknown)
{
STDMETHOD  (QueryInterface)     (THIS_ REFIID, void **) PURE;
STDMETHOD_ (ULONG, AddRef)      (THIS) PURE;
STDMETHOD_ (ULONG, Release)     (THIS) PURE;
STDMETHOD_  (BOOL, hallo)           (THIS) PURE;

};

#endif // _IEXAMPLE_H_
```

class1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace fb_dll
{
[Guid("D685CD6F-5D76-4868-9CE4-8ABBF60ACA06")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface DBCOM_Interface
{
    [DispId(1)]
    bool hello();
} 


[Guid("0C8C75A-729F-43A4-9006-577BF627FA75")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class DBCOM_Class : DBCOM_Interface
{
    public DBCOM_Class()
    {
        //Init();
        //MessageBox.Show("jauaua");
    }

    public bool hello()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("jauaua");
        return true;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: You're trying to call a function called `hallo`, but you've defined a function called `hello`.

Comment: yes in my iexample.h as you can see.

Comment: What error do you have? Also, ComInterfaceType should be Dual or IUnknown to be used in C/C++. PS: CoInitialize shouldn't be tested against zero, it can be S_OK, S_FALSE or negative values (but that's not related to your problem).

Comment: Also, I'm not sure it should be declared as `STDMETHOD_(BOOL)`. Maybe you'd need to use `STDMETHOD(hello) (THIS_ VARIANT_BOOL *pRet)`. Or maybe you should go the extra mile and write an IDL file so you can have an auto-generated header file for the C program and a type library for the C# dll.

Comment: You're really asking for trouble by trying to define the same interface in two places, in two unrelated formats: you will make a mistake. You should use IDL to define the interface, and let MIDL compiler do it's job: it's there for a reason.

Comment: "Also, ComInterfaceType should be Dual or IUnknown to be used in C/C++"  
this was is it. the cominterfacetype was wrong.
  
thx